# Script node missing in node editor

Tags: node-editor

Following a osl in [cycles tutorial](http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/introduction-to-osl-in-blender-cycles/) And the option of what shading system to use is missing and also I cannot activate the scripting node when I am in node editing mode. I am using blender 2.67b, And I have tried to use the search option (as shown in attached image). If any body knows what is/or what i am doing wrong could they please inform me. Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make sure that your *Render Engine* is to *Cycles* and that you are in the ***Shader*** node editor, not the compositor.

[image]

The *Script* node is there..

[image]

The changes in the *Render* panel were more than likely made in the space of time from 2.65 to 2.67.